# Remplazar CR/LF en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy intentando eliminar los saltos de lineas que tiene una cadena que exporto a una base de datos.

el código que tengo es :

```
SELECT  WORKITEM,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(CH_PARRAFO, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') FROM [DPS_CBRS].[dbo].[CH_PARRAFO]
```

Pero me arroja un error

> Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

que me falta en el código o que esta mal?

Comment: Veo que utlilizas **CH_PARRAFO** como nombre de columna y nombre de tabla. Es así o la tabla tiene otro nombre?

Comment: Encontré el error estimado, era el tipo de dato, la columna estaba en text y la cambie a varchar y ahora funciono el código.

Comment: El código funciona con tipo de dato Varchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendrás que convertir el campo a VARCHAR con por ejemplo la función CAST:

```
SELECT  WORKITEM,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(CH_PARRAFO AS VARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS CH_PARRAFO_LIMPIO
FROM [DPS_CBRS].[dbo].[CH_PARRAFO]
```